Почему происходит потеря точности градиента при низких значениях?

Подскажите с чем связанна потеря точности градиента при низких значениях? Особенно заметно при наклоненном градиенте:


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
    black 0,
    black 2px,
    orange 2px,
    orange 4px);
}




Как только выставляешь вопрос на обозрение - появляется решение. Если установить не четкие границы, а с небольшим переходом, то нарушение исправляется:


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
    transparent 0,
    #d1ffff 1px,
    #d1ffff 2px,
    transparent 3px,
    transparent 4px);
}





Это извесная проблема. Проблема с потерей точности градиента при низких значениях связана с тем, что браузеры рендерят такие градиенты по принципу растеризации (преобразование в пиксели), и при малых значениях полосы градиента могут не точно соответствовать расчетам из-за ограничений разрешения экрана и алгоритмов сглаживания.
К сожалению, простого решения она не имеет. Из полумер - Попробуйте увеличить ширину полос, чтобы градиент был более заметен и стабильным, например, сделайте полосы 4-6px вместо 2px.
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black 0, black 4px, orange 4px, orange 8px);
Добавление фильтров сглаживания: Применение CSS-фильтров вроде filter: blur() может помочь немного сгладить градиент, но этот подход может несколько размыть изображение:
filter: blur(0.5px);
Заменить на повторяющееся изображение (возможно SVG патерн)
Проблема имеет физический характер и зависит от мощности вашего монитора, видеокарты, и возможности обрабатывать графику. Сам сталкивался при создании миллиметровке средствами CSS

Спасибо за объяснение), это расширит мои знания о рендере.
